# Tomcat Authentication Request

Tags: java, web, tomcat, jaas

**Quick Question:** Does Tomcat authentication (JAAS) maintain the `HttpRequest` object throughout the authentication process?

For example, let's say the request has an attribute `id`. Is this attribute maintained after the authentication flow, such as:

`Custom Form` -> `LoginContext` -> `Appropriate Login Module` -> `Creation of user principal` -> `Custom Form`?

After all these processes, does the request still contain the `id`? If it is maintained, how exactly is it preserved?

PS I am not talking about Callbacks.